# How to merge 2 Collections from different types into one custom type on LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I want to create a list of objects based of 2 lists from different types.
I have a code snippet right now that works, but I would like to see if it can be converted into LINQ to make it smaller and more efficient.

```
List<Region> regions = new List<Region>
            {
                new Region
                {
                    Name = "America"
                },
                new Region
                {
                    Name = "Europe"
                },
                new Region
                {
                    Name = "Asia"
                }
            };

            List<Concept> concepts = new List<Concept>
            {
                new Concept
                {
                    Name = "Population"
                },
                new Concept
                {
                    Name = "Location"
                },
                new Concept
                {
                    Name = "Temperature"
                },
                new Concept
                {
                    Name = "President"
                }
            };

            List<object> result = new List<object>();

            foreach (var region in regions)
            {
                foreach (var concept in concepts)
                {
                    result.Add(new { region = region.Name, concept = concept.Name });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the equivalent of a cross join in LINQ like this:

```
var regionConcepts = regions.SelectMany(x => concepts.Select(y => new { Region = x.Name, Concept = y.Name }));
```

Answer (score 0):

With linq query:

```
        var results = from region in regions
                      from concept in concepts
                      select new
                      {
                          region = region.Name,
                          concept = concept.Name
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = regions.SelectMany(r => concepts, (r, c) => new Tuple<Region, Concept>(r, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent of what your code currently does using LINQ.

```
List<object> resultSet = regions.SelectMany(region => 
                        concepts.Select(concept => new { 
                                Region = region.Name, Concept = concept.Name })
                        )
                        .Cast<object>()
                        .ToList();
```

Another variant:

```
List<object> resultSet = (from region in regions
                          from concept in concepts
                          select new
                          {
                              region = region.Name,
                              concept = concept.Name
                          }).Cast<object>()
                            .ToList();
```